# htaccess is partially working on ip server domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have a ip server say 23.43.53.23
and a cms is a root folder my index.jsp and second.jsp is there

now when i apply short changes in .htaccess file like :

```
RewriteEngine on
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex second.jsp
</IfModule>
```

then's it works...

but when i put something rewrite rule like

```
RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^second/([^/]*)/?(.*)$ second.jsp?name=$1&page=$2
```

and pass this value

http://XX.XX.XX.XX:8080/cms/second.jsp?name=en&page=ro

then it is not working..

any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cant use rewrite rule in apache tomcat use it with mod_jk or virtual host

Answer (score 1):

You look for *second* at the beginning of the path, but the path has *cms* there. So change it to:

```
RewriteRule ^cms/second/([^/]*)/?(.*)$ second.jsp?name=$1&page=$2
```